# Acess to class by javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function someFunction(element) {

$(element '.some-class').css({'background-color' : 'red'});

}

someFunction('.test');
```

I can`t add css property to '.test .some-class', please help

Comment: That's because you aren't using valid Javascript. Try  `$(element + ' .some-class').css ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is currently 2 separate strings, so you need to combine them with operator `+`:

```
$(element + ' .some-class').css({'background-color' : 'red'});

}
```

Additional space before `.some-class` is required, otherwise your selector will be on the same element.

Comment: oh tnx, I have tried that, but forgot to add a gap in class

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to get elements with the class ".some-class" **inside** an element with the class ".test" . . . if that is right, then you would be best off using `.find()`:

```
$(element).find('.some-class').css({'background-color' : 'red'});
```

If I am misunderstanding your question and you want elements with **both** the ".some-class" and ".test" classes, then you would change that to `.filter()`:

```
$(element).filter('.some-class').css({'background-color' : 'red'})
```

### **Update:**

**dotnetom**'s solution works just great too . . . my approach should be slightly more efficient, but it shouldn't be a big deal either way.